# Subscripts for primed variables

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

When I add a subscript to a primed variable, the subscript is rendered lower than when it is a subscript to an unprimed variable.

For example, when I compile

```
$l_x l'_x l_x l'_x l_x l'_x$
```

I get

[image]

The subscript x is at a different height for the primed variables and the unprimed ones.

Any one have any idea why this is happening? And how I can fix this so that the subscript of the primed variable appears at the same height? (Or am I doing something wrong?)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This behaviour is intended, but not always desired. My somewhat neglected [`subdepth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subdepth) package alters this so the subscript height is constant in these situations. Just load the package.

Comment: FYI subdepth doesn't always ensure the subscript height is constant. For example, `$l_1 l^y_1$`.

Comment: Seems like the best solution.

Comment: @Lev: Hmmm, you're right. I've added a [bug](http://github.com/wspr/subdepth/issues/issue/2) to the issue tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Try this. It's a bit cumbersome, but, I think, semantically reasonable:

```
$l^{}_x l'_x l^{}_x l'_x l^{}_x l'_x$
```

[image: Rendered]

Comment: Only just saw Will Robertson's answer (`subdepth`). Probably the better way to go.

Comment: @Whoever gave this a down vote: would you care to comment?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `l\mathrlap{'}_x` (you need to `usepackage{mathtools}` to get the `mathrlap` command), which positions the subscript exactly like in `l_x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put curly braces around the object you're subscripting, e.g. {l'}_x, the subscript will appear at the same height as the others. However, the spacing of the prime and the subscript will not be the same as in your example, so this may not be the solution you want. You can also put curly braces around the object on which you want a prime, e.g. {l_x}', but this also alters the spacing of the prime and the subscript.

Comment: Yeah, the first solution has the problem that the subscript is too far from the variable. Ideally I'd like a solution that looks exactly like the unprimed version.