# How to raise a subscript?

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts

For some reason, I need to write a “minus” sign as a subscript on some symbols, but if I simply write `$\Pi_{-}$` the result looks kind of odd. I've found that `$\Pi{\scriptstyle -}$` looks reasonably better. But if want to add this “minus” subscript *and* a prime, then I get an unwanted space between the prime and the fake subscript.

[image]

So, is there a way to simply raise the subscript a bit?

*Note:* I've considered writing something like `$\Pi\mathrlap{'}{\scriptstyle -}$`, which actually produces something like I want. But then it is difficult to define a macro such that I can write `\Neg{\Pi}` and `\Neg{\Pi'}` to add the “subscript minus” on the symbol I supply as an argument.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can put `{\raisebox{2pt}{$\scriptstyle-$}}` in the subscript. You may need to play with `\mathchoice` if you want a solution that will work in subsubscripts as well.

Edit: Or better yet, `\mathpalette`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
```

and use `$\Pi_{\raisemath{2pt}{-}}$`.

Comment: I went with this answer because it has the least trickery and works fine to define other macros.

Comment: Nearly 4 years later this and still people find this post helpful. This seems to be the best and easily "automated" solution out there. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your question depends on what behaviour of the subscript you expect. What TeX does by default is that it gives the subscript a lower position if there's also a superscript; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3223/1235). If that's OK for you then you can use Harald's solution. If not then you can use the following hack. Beware, this `\Piminus` accepts `'` or nothing as an argument, but nothing else.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\savedxvi
\newdimen\savedxvii
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Piminus{%
    \@ifnextchar'{\print@pi'\@gobble}
                 {\print@pi\relax\relax}}
\def\print@pi#1#2{%
    \savedxvi=\fontdimen16\textfont2
    \savedxvii=\fontdimen17\textfont2
    \mbox{%
    $\fontdimen16\textfont2=0pt
     \fontdimen17\textfont2=0pt
     \Pi_{\smash-}#1$}%
    \fontdimen16\textfont2=\savedxvi
    \fontdimen17\textfont2=\savedxvii
    #2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Piminus \Piminus' \Pi_-$
\end{document}
```

Short explanation: `\fontdimen16` is the amount the subscript is lowered when there is no superscript, `\fontdimen17` is used when there is a superscript. They have to be restored since they aren't local to the group.

EDIT:

To explain a bit more: Not only are the changes of the `\fontdimen` parameters global, you also have to keep in mind that it's of no use to change the value of a `\fontdimen` parameter within one math list `$ ... $` several times. Only the values valid at the *end* of the math list will be used for the whole list. This is the reason why in my above solution I used `\mbox{$ ... $}`.

Here's a slightly more elaborate version that allows multiple primes, and also e.g. `'^2`. It hacks into TeX's ingenious definition of `'`. One could also implement that `\Piminus^2` works as is should, but this I leave as an exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newdimen\savedxvi
\newdimen\savedxvii
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\restoredimen{%
    \fontdimen16\textfont2=\savedxvi
    \fontdimen17\textfont2=\savedxvii}
\newcommand*\qwe{$\egroup\restoredimen}
\newcommand*\Piminus{%
    \@ifnextchar'{\expandafter\Pi@minus\@gobble}
                 {\print@pi\qwe}}
\def\Pi@minus{\print@pi{^\bgroup\aftergroup\qwe\prim@s}}
\def\print@pi#1{%
    \savedxvi=\fontdimen16\textfont2
    \savedxvii=\fontdimen17\textfont2
    \hbox\bgroup%
    $\fontdimen16\textfont2=0pt
     \fontdimen17\textfont2=0pt
     \Pi_{\smash-}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\Piminus \Piminus' \Piminus'' \Pi_- \Piminus'^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, and is probably *the* way to raise a subscript. The odd thing is that the change is global, and then one needs to do a lot of macro hackery to get the desired result. I know it can be done, but it would be a pain to make it work with e.g. `\Piminus''`

Comment: @Juan: I've failed more than once to implement changes of the `\fontdimen` s correctly. This was one of the reasons why I gave this slightly trickery answer: to show what one has to keep in mind when working with `\fontdimen`. I'll add another more trickery version that allows multiple primes.

Comment: Strange things with luatex it doesn't react to any value changing in assignment of ...\textfont2=0pt... while pdflatex works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few thoughts,

First it might help to use the \prime command as in `^{\prime}` rather than using a tick, both for look and it probably macros better as well.

You might try playing with the overset command i.e. `\Pi\overset{^{\prime}}{_{-}}`

Also the [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/mhchem.html) package has done a lot of work to deal with overset scripts, as chemists need to deal with similar problems in formulae.

Finally you might check to see if there is a character you would rather use for your - rather than a -. A great reference is the [short math guide](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) from AMS.

Comment: `'` does nothing else than putting `^{\prime}`! (And `''` puts `^{\prime\prime}`; ingenious definition of `'`.)