# Moving the bar on hbar

Tags: macros, mathdesign

I've been using the [mathdesign](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/) package (specifically with the garamond font), and whenever I try using `\hbar`, the bar is much too high and to the left.

In order to fix this, I wanted to know how to redefine `\hbar` to be an h with a bar that I can move around until it looks aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeX defines `\hbar` as `\mathchar'26`, followed by a backspace of 9 math units (`\mkern-9mu`), followed by the letter `h`. Or, more specifically,

```
\def\hbar{{\mathchar'26\mkern-9muh}% \hbar
```

In order to provide the flexibility to overlap these two elements (the bar and the letter), we break it into two separate components, focussing on moving the bar in the correct position and then merely typesetting the `h` afterwards. Moving the bar left/right is obtained by a straight-forward `\hspace*`. Raising/lowering the bar is performed by the macro `\raisemath{<len>}{...}`, obtained from [How to raise a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/how-to-raise-a-subscript/5192#5192):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
```

Overlap of the bar with the `h` is obtained by `\mathrlap` (provided by the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)). Easy macro definition is provided by `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}% \raisemath{<len>}{...}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
\NewDocumentCommand{\newhbar}{O{0pt} O{0pt}}{% \newhbar[<horz len>][<vert len>]
  \ensuremath{\mathrlap{\raisemath{#2}{\hspace*{#1}{\mathchar'26\mkern-9mu}}}h}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \verb!\hbar!: & \hbar \\
    \verb!\newhbar!: & \newhbar \\
    \verb!\newhbar[4pt]!: & \newhbar[4pt] \\
    \verb!\newhbar[-1pt][1.5pt]!: & \newhbar[-1pt][1.5pt] \\
    \verb!\newhbar[2pt][-4pt]!: & \newhbar[2pt][-4pt] \\
    \verb!\tfrac{\hbar}{2}!: & \tfrac{\hbar}{2} \\
    \verb!\tfrac{\newhbar}{2}!: & \tfrac{\newhbar}{2} \\
    \verb!\tfrac{\pi}{\newhbar[0pt][-1pt]}!: & \tfrac{\pi}{\newhbar[0pt][-1pt]}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: hbar that can be modified]

You can play around with the optional parameters for `\newhbar[<horz len>][<vert len>]`. The first parameter `<horz len>` moves the bar left/right, while the second `<vert len>` moves it up/down. They are optional, but cannot be empty. It would be possible to extend this to accommodate such empty parameters.

Comment: Thanks! This is so close to what I want, I just can't seem to lower it (putting a negative number as the second optional argument isn't changing anything, and 0 is still a bit too high).

Comment: @thequark: I've updated the solution to now take regular LaTeX lengths. You should be able to adequately specify negative lengths to move the bar up/down.

Comment: Thanks! I'm certainly accepting this. Just thought I'd add one comment that it looks like the bar changes locations based on where it shows up in math (if it's at the beginning vs. after some other variables or equal sign). It's so subtle that it could just be my eyes...

Comment: I just came up with another issue: Whenever mathmode makes `\hbar` smaller (e.g. in a `\tfrac` command), the bar gets pushed upwards. I believe this is due to the fact that the phantom `h` doesn't scale appropriately. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @thequark: I've completely revamped the code and added some clarification for the use of certain elements. Hope this serves your needs.