# Barred q symbol doesn't scale properly

Tags: symbols

Using the answer to the question [moving the bar on hbar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30291/moving-the-bar-on-hbar/30294#comment489092_30294) (copy/paste and tweaking the parameters, and replacing `mathchar'26` by the shorter `mathchar'55`), I was able to create a barred q. Unfortunately, this symbol behaves badly when I use `\qbar` as an index.

[image]

I use the font package `eulervm`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\qbar}{\ensuremath{\mathrlap{\raisemath{-3.2}{\hspace*{3.2pt}
{\mathchar'55\mkern-9mu}}}q}}

\begin{document}
{\Huge$\qbar$} \qquad $\qbar$ \qquad $U_{\qbar}$
\end{document}
```

What code should I use to get the same symbol in both cases? I also noticed that I had to reconfigure the paramters in the definition of `\qbar` for this question, presumably there was some interaction with the other packages or options... This is first time I'm attempting to create a symbol in this fashion. If you know of better ways, or can provide me with a resource that explains how to do this in general, that would be great too!

Comment: Could someone include a picture of the output please?

Comment: No, because the example doesn't compile

Comment: @egreg It compiles on my end...

Comment: I agree with egreg: your code didn't compile. I have edited it and it does now but all of the bars on the `q`'s are out.

Comment: @egreg thanks! I guess the package was already loaded from my main document (?)

Comment: @egreg I corrected the parameters, the absence of `mathtools` must have been what mixed it up in the first place.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry about the mathtools omission, I have changed the parameters to their original values, this gives the desired spacing.

Comment: Part of the reason why your code did not compile before is that `-3.2` is not a valid first argument for `\raisemath`: it needs a length not a number. With your edit the code does not compile again giving the error `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a different approach; the absolute measures like 3.2pt can work just for one size.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{eulervm,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\qbar}{\text{\q@bar}}
\newcommand{\q@bar}{%
  \vphantom{$\m@th q$}%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th q$\cr
    \hidewidth\smash{\raisebox{-0.7ex}{$\m@th\mathchar'55$}}\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\fbox{\Huge $q$}\,\fbox{\Huge$\qbar$} \quad $\qbar$ \quad $U_{\qbar}\ne U_{q}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The two `\fbox` command show that the bounding box of `\qbar` is the same as for `q`.

If you want that the bar crosses the descender, then add some horizontal space, changing the definition of `\q@bar` into

```
\newcommand{\q@bar}{%
  \vphantom{$\m@th q$}%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th q$\cr
    \hidewidth\kern.3em\smash{\raisebox{-0.7ex}{$\m@th\mathchar'55$}}\hidewidth\cr}%
}
```

The above input would give

[image]

Comment: How would you move the bar to the right? So that it sticks out equally to both sides of the vertical bar?

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves it : ) Where can I learn how to write this properly, as opposed to copy/pasting answers form TSE?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Maybe 0.33em is better; adjust to suit.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to use Lua- or XeLaTeX, you might want to use the unicode [`U+A757`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a757/index.htm) for this. Just look for [a font which supports this symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a757/fontsupport.htm) and load it like in my MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\qbar}{\ensuremath{\text{\symbol{"A757}}}}

\begin{document}
    A test for EB Garamond in math mode \fbox{$\qbar$} \fbox{$\mathrm{q}$} and text mode \fbox{\qbar} \fbox{q}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unluckily I can't find a slanted or italic version.

You may also define a symbol with another font as your surrounding text:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\qbar}{\ensuremath{\text{{\setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"A757}}}}}

\begin{document}
    \[\qbar_{\qbar_\qbar}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are some different symbols I could find on my system:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond}\symbol{"A757}
    \setmainfont{dejavusans.ttf}\symbol{"A757}
    \setmainfont{freeserif.otf}\symbol{"A757}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"A757}

    %\setmainfont{EB Garamond}\symbol{"A756} % not available in upper case
    \setmainfont{dejavusans.ttf}\symbol{"A756}
    \setmainfont{freeserif.otf}\symbol{"A756}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"A756} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some quick (scriptable?) way in which you searched your fonts for a particular symbol? A note on how you did that would be generally useful.

Comment: @dedded Just use the "Local Font List" which is linked in the second link in my answer. Here it is for this very character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%EA%9D%97+-+LATIN+SMALL+LETTER+Q+WITH+STROKE+THROUGH+DESCENDER+%28U%2BA757%29