# Double Subscript for Subsequences

Tags: subscripts

What's the best way to write subsequences?  `$x_n_i$` gives an error, while `$x_{n_{i}}$` works, but it just looks like `$x_{ni}$` (the `i` isn't lowered enough below the `n`)...

Comment: Related question: [How to raise a superscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5191/2693). The accepted answer there can be given a negative amount to lower the second subscript as much as you like.

Comment: My honest answer is *there are none*.

Comment: I don't think the two questions are related. Rather, the current question is about *how* to group the indexing characters in order to achieve output that's both visually as well as mathematically pleasing.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled by your statement that `$x_{n_i}$` would create output which "just looks like" that of `$x_{ni}$` -- this is not the case in the following MWE (minimum working example). I have a hunch that what you want is `$x_{n_i}$`, but read on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
$x_{ni}$ or ${x_n}_i$ or $x_{n_i}$?
\end{verbatim}
$x_{ni}$ or ${x_n}_i$ or $x_{n_i}$?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, the first expression, `$x_{ni}$`, can't be what you want. Note that `${x_n}_i$` and `$x_{n_i}$` are both valid expressions from a purely syntactic point of view. However, they do *not* create the same output. In the former case, the character `i` is both *lowered by a smaller amount* and has a *larger font size* than is the case in the latter. (To be a bit TeXnical, in the first two expressions above, `n` and `i` are both typeset in "scriptstyle", whereas in the third expression `n` is in scriptstyle and `i` is in "scriptscriptstyle". For Computer Modern math fonts, "scriptstyle" is 30% linearly reduced from "textstyle", and "scriptscriptstyle" is 30% reduced from "scriptstyle" -- or ca 50% linearly reduced from "textstyle". Thus, if the textstyle font size is 10pt, scriptsize is 7pt and scriptscriptsize is 5pt.)

These differences in appearance are, of course, not accidental: in the middle expression above, the symbol `i` is a subscript/index to the subformula `$x_n$`, whereas in the final expression `i` indexes `n` which, in turn, indexes `x`. Put differently, in the final expression `${n_i}$` is a subformula that serves to index `x`.

If there's *any* chance for ambiguity as to which characters are supposed to index which other characters, you should not hesitate to use parentheses, brackets, or braces -- or whatever grouping symbols are appropriate in your math writing style -- to clarify the intended meaning of your writing.

**Addendum**, prompted by a follow-up communication from the OP. As the image above illustrates, there's not much visual difference in the appearance of the first and second cases, i.e., of `$x_{ni}$` and `${x_n}_i$`. In both cases, (a) the `n` and `i` characters are in `scriptsize`, and (b) the `i`'s are set below the baseline by the same amount. The only visual difference, then, is that TeX sets the `n` in the second case in so-called "cramped subscript" mode, which differs from the "ordinary subscript" position by a (very) small amount.

Comment: Thanks!  I think it was actually the font I was using that didn't make `$x_{n_i}$` look lowered enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which font were you using?

Comment: I was using the Arev font, with `\usepackage{fouriernc}`.  Do you happen to know of any similar fonts which don't make sub-subscripts look terrible?

Comment: See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: I am (and have been) using `$x_{n_i}$`, but in Arev, this did not look very good; it actually looked a lot like `${x_n}_i$`.

Comment: In arev, the letter `i` definitely looks very skinny, even anorexic, when it appears in the second-level subscript position. Sadly, only very few font families have so-called "multiple master" designs; if they're lacking this aspect, they'll look skinny at sizes well below the so-called "design size", and they'll look bulky at large sizes.

Comment: @Mico: Excellent answer. Somehow I never saw this question before, and think that this is the first time I thought I was reading an "egreg" answer and it turned out not to be one of his.

Comment: @PeterGrill -- Wow, thanks for the compliment!!