# Double Superscript

Tags: superscripts

I am trying to find a similar question but they all seem to suggest something completely different.

I want to create a superscript for a superscript. Essentially: `2^2^n`

Comment: ... $2^{2^{n}}$ ?

Comment: See also [Double Subscript for Subsequences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38100/5001). That posting is, as the title implies, about double *sub*scripts. Replacing the `_` characters with `^` characters in the discussions, you could learn all you need to know about double superscripts as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A superscript of a superscript should be grouped. So, depending on what you're after exactly, you can do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$2^{2^n}\ {2^2}^n$

\end{document}
```

The first example is `2` to the power (`2^n`); using a similar syntax, the styles used are `\textstyle^{\scriptstyle^\scriptstyle}`. The second example is (`2^2`) to the power `n` with the styles denoted by `{\textstyle^\scriptstyle}^\scriptstyle`.

Comment: The second possibility given here is very unclear and should be equipped with explicit parentheses like `$(2^2)^n$`.

Comment: Do [be careful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472826/126395) - sometimes `2^{2^n}` can be better than `{2^2}^n`.