# 2nd line of equation is indenting to the right

Tags: equations, alignment, split

I have looked at answers to this question extensively and tried copied them but the second line of my equation keeps indenting to far to the right. How do I make it look normal?

```
            \begin{documentclass}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
              \textrm{Y}_{it} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ \beta_2\textrm{economic slack}_{it} + \beta_3\textrm{economic slack}*\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ & \\ \beta_4 X_{it} + \sum fe_{i} + \sum fe_{t} + \mu_{it} 
              \end{split}
        \end{equation}

        \end{documentclass}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Regarding the subscripts, you might want to have a look at: [Double Subscript for Subsequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38100/134144)

Comment: Is that better now?

Comment: You haven't specified an alignment point (with `&`) in the first line.  That's necessary.  Also (off topic) it's more usual to put a `+` at the beginning of a continuation line rather than at the end of the first, broken, line.

Comment: By the way, a "compilable" example should start with `\documentclass`.  (And `\usepackage` belongs in the preamble.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton First of all thank you for the convention help, I didn't know that. But I do have a & after the line break

Comment: You need a matching `&` in both lines, to set the position where the second line should start.  The `&` at the end of the first line isn't really doing anything.  What I'd do is move that to just before the `=`, and start the second line with `&\qquad +` so that it doesn't line up exactly with the `=`.  Take a look at the `amsmath` user guide for examples.

Comment: Well, your equation is too long to be on a line. Please do not "textize" your equation too much - equation is math!

Comment: do you really have a `documentclass` environment??, please test the code you have posted and check that  anyone can run it to see the issue that you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would use more lines, with at most one of those “verbose variable” per line:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{Y}_{it} = \beta_{0}
&+\beta_{1}(\textrm{Education Construction})_{it} \\
&+\beta_2(\textrm{Economic Slack})_{it} \\
&+\beta_3(\textrm{Economic Slack})\cdot(\textrm{Education Construction})_{it} \\
&+\beta_4 X_{it} + \sum fe_{i} + \sum fe_{t} + \mu_{it}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  There are a few issues with your example code.

**Basic Document Format**

Since you do not appear to be defining a [`documentclass`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Document_classes) here, you should start with a simple [preamble](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Preamble) that defines which documentclass you are using.  If you are unsure, `article` is a common choice.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Be sure to include the beginning and ending of your document (in fact, you should `\end{...}` anything that you `\begin{...}`).  Including packages with `\usepackage{...}` should go *before* `\begin{document}` but *after* `\documentclass{...}`.

Applying these principles, so far your code should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
          \textrm{Y}_{it} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ \beta_2\textrm{economic slack}_{it} + \beta_3\textrm{economic slack}*\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ & \\ \beta_4 X_{it} + \sum fe_{i} + \sum fe_{t} + \mu_{it} 
          \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**How To Handle Long Equations**

There are already questions that address this problem (for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8936/how-to-break-a-long-equation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines)), but I suggest you use a simple `align` approach.  You designate the location within the equation you would like to align your following lines to (left-align) with the `&` character.  I tend to pick the `=`, so it's as simple as `&=`.  You do not need `split` or `equation` in this case, you simply use the [`align` environment](https://latex.wikia.org/wiki/Align_(environment)).  A simple replacement of your above method with the align method will yield:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \textrm{Y}_{it} &= \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ \beta_2\textrm{economic slack}_{it} + \beta_3\textrm{economic slack}*\textrm{Education Construction}_{it} \\
    &+ \beta_4 X_{it} + \sum fe_{i} + \sum fe_{t} + \mu_{it} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And to shorten or lengthen lines, simply change where you want to break them up at.  For example, your equation would fit on the page if constructed as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \textrm{Y}_{it} &= \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}\textrm{Education Construction}_{it}+ \beta_2\textrm{economic slack}_{it} \\
    &+ \beta_3\textrm{economic slack}*\textrm{Education Construction}_{it} \\
    &+ \beta_4 X_{it} + \sum fe_{i} + \sum fe_{t} + \mu_{it} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Final Comments**

@JouleV makes a good argument in the comments that your equation does contain a lot of text.  I suggest removing or reducing the text, which would also help it to fit into more compact space.

Hope this helps!