# How do you write an exponent of an exponent?

Tags: syntax

I am trying to write 2 to the power of 2 to the power of k, and $2^2^k$ instead gives 2 to the power of 2k.

Comment: Try `$2^{2^k}$` or `${2^2}^k$` or maybe even `$({2^2})^k$`, depending on your context.

Comment: See also [Double Subscript for Subsequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38100/5001). To adapt that posting to your use case, simply replace all instances of "subscript" with "superscript".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the curly braces, grouping the exponents:

`$2^{2^k}$`

`$m_{n_k}$`

or even

`$m_{n^2}$`

A pair of curly braces creates a group - it means that TeX in many cases treats grouped part of the formula as one single object.

[image]