# Problem with \SetAlgoLined in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I am very new to Latex. I have problem with \SetAlgoLined in algorithm2e. As seen from the picture, inside the while loop the line seem to be normal. I don't know why outside the while loop, the line seem strange.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm2e}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{Subscribe}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Publish}
  \SetKw{Set}{set}
 \SetKw{Read}{read}
 \SetAlFnt{\large}
 \SetAlCapFnt{\large}
 \SetAlCapNameFnt{\large}
 \caption{Single Robot Auto Navigation}

  \Input{initialize\_state, custom\_waypose ($q_i,\alpha_i$), robot\_status, camera\_interrupt, object\_depth}
  \Output{robot\_pose ($p_i,\alpha_i$), sphere\_marker\_position ($q$) }
  
  \If{finished initialize\_state}{
     \Read {custom\_waypose}\;
  \For{waypoint ($q_i$) in custom\_waypose:}{
    \For{wayorientation ($\theta_i$) in custom\_waypose:}{
        \Set{WAIT to robot\_status}\;
         $p_i = q_i$\; 
         $\theta_i = \alpha_i$\;
        return waypose\;
    \While{waiting robot\_status}{
      \If {robot reached goal}{
            break\;}          
            
    \If {camera_interrupt}{
    $q_i_x = p_i_x+ object\_depth * sin(\theta_i)$\;
    $q_i_y = p_i_y+ object\_depth * cos(\theta_i)$ \;
    return sphere marker (q)\;
    end program\;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
\end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

[image: Inside the while loop the line seem to be normal. I don't know why outside the while loop, the line seem strange.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code gives multiple errors. Solving them, solves your problem.

1. Missing $ inserted.

- `camera_interrupt` -> `camera\_interrupt`

2. 4 times Double subscript

- `q_i_x` -> `q_{i_x}` (if that is what you mean), etc.
- see also [Double Subscript for Subsequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38100/123129)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm2e}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Subscribe}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Publish}
    \SetKw{Set}{set}
    \SetKw{Read}{read}
    \SetAlFnt{\large}
    \SetAlCapFnt{\large}
    \SetAlCapNameFnt{\large}
    \caption{Single Robot Auto Navigation}

  \Input{initialize\_state, custom\_waypose ($q_i,\alpha_i$), robot\_status, camera\_interrupt, object\_depth}
  \Output{robot\_pose ($p_i,\alpha_i$), sphere\_marker\_position ($q$) }
  
  \If{finished initialize\_state}{
     \Read {custom\_waypose}\;
  \For{waypoint ($q_i$) in custom\_waypose:}{
    \For{wayorientation ($\theta_i$) in custom\_waypose:}{
        \Set{WAIT to robot\_status}\;
         $p_i = q_i$\; 
         $\theta_i = \alpha_i$\;
        return waypose\;
    \While{waiting robot\_status}{
      \If {robot reached goal}{
            break\;}          
            
    \If {camera\_interrupt}{
    $q_{i_x} = p_{i_x}+ object\_depth * sin(\theta_i)$\;
    $q_{i_y} = p_{i_y}+ object\_depth * cos(\theta_i)$ \;
    return sphere marker (q)\;
    end program\;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
\end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!