# redefine subscripts

Tags: subscripts

The code `a_x_y` is undefined in pdflatex, it could mean `a_{x_y}`, `{a_x}_y`, `a_{xy}`, or `a_x{}_y`.

Is there a way to define `a_x_y` as `a_{xy}` by default, as is in XeTex?

Comment: Sorry I do not follow, what exactly do you mean by `Is there a way to define a_{xy} as default, as is in XeTex` ??

Comment: `$a_x_y_$` is same with PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX and even PDFTeX or XeTeX: “Double subscript” error. So your questionn is very unclear.

Comment: BTW: IMHO `$a_{xy}$` is the least intuitive meaning of `$a_x_y$`. I've never seen such an interpretation before. But this is only an opinion.

Comment: @cabohah In math, it’s quite common to have multiple sub- and superscripts added one by one, e.g. `\mathcal{F}_{1x}` (the sheaf `\mathcal{F}_1` stalked at `x`). Ideally, you would like such constructions to be macro-based, but this becomes hard due to multiple subscripts. If you define e.g. `\newcommand\stalk[2]{#1_{#2}}` and `\newcommand\sheafFone{\mathcal{F}_1}`, then `\stalk{\sheafFone}{x}` fails miserably. In this case, indeed, allowing multiple subscripts to be stacked would improve the situation significantly. And yes, I think the syntax would be entirely intuitive.

Comment: this is an error in all tex variants including xetex,  you can not change this while keeping `_` with its subscript meaning, of course you could make it active and do the parsing "by hand" but that will break some things.

Comment: Since LaTeX cannot guess if the user want really `$a_{x_y}$` or `${a_x}_y$`, IMHO the question explain itself why define double subscripts to make something, other than a error, is not a good idea, even if this make harder the use of some macros.

Comment: See also [Double Subscript for Subsequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38100/5001).