# Understanding expansion of \mathpalette

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm trying to make sense of the `\mathpalette` code used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5192/71531). To repeat it below:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
$\Pi_{\raisemath{2pt}{-}}$
```

When I did `\tracingmacros=1`, the interesting part of the log file was:

```
 \raisemath #1->\mathpalette {\raisem@th {#1}}
 #1<-2pt

 \mathpalette #1#2->\mathchoice {#1\displaystyle {#2}}{#1\textstyle {#2}}
 {#1\scriptstyle {#2}}{#1\scriptscriptstyle {#2}}
 #1<-\raisem@th {2pt}
 #2<--

 \raisem@th #1#2#3->\raisebox {#1}{$#2#3$}
 #1<-2pt
 #2<-\displaystyle 
 #3<--

 etc...

 \raisem@th #1#2#3->\raisebox {#1}{$#2#3$}
 #1<-2pt
 #2<-\textstyle 
 #3<--

 etc...
```

From the code `\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}` in the definition of `\raisemath`, I'd think that `\mathpalette` only is given one parameter in this instance, `\raisem@th{2pt}`. So, how does the second parameter, `-`, end up being passed to `\mathpalette`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

True, only a single argument is given to `\mathpalette` within the `\raisemath` macro. The second argument to `\mathpalette` is grabbed from the remainder of the input stream.

Here's a smaller example exhibiting the same setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\abcd}[1]{\defg{#1}}
\newcommand{\defg}[2]{#1-#2}
\begin{document}
\abcd{1234}{5678}
\end{document}
```

It is clear that `\abcd` only takes a single argument as the definition only has `[1]` - that argument based on the input is `{1234}`. Therefore,

```
\abcd{1234}{5678}
```

expands to

```
\defg{1234}{5678}
```

with `{5678}` remaining in the input stream. Now, `\defg` gobbles the next two arguments, the first being `{1234}` and the second being `{5678}`.

---

Here's another practical example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\boldtext}{\textbf}
\begin{document}
\boldtext{abcd}
\end{document}
```

`\boldtext` is defined to not take any argument. However, we know `\textbf` takes an argument. So, it suffices to use `\boldtext` as a replacement for `\textbf` without technically having to grab the argument for `\textbf`. Another way to define it (although not really necessary) would be to grab the argument explicitly:

```
\newcommand{\boldtext}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

Why not just define things explicitly? It depends on what you want to do with the argument. If category code changes are involved, then it may be best to *not* grab arguments explicitly.

Comment: \section also extensively makes use of these methods :-)