# vertical spacing in one equation (not align)

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical

```
\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{exp\left(\frac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)}
\end{equation}
```

That's my equation and here's its appearance 
[image]

I think I can change the vertical spacing in the exp part. Because it looks like frac line touches the N and V in the document.  But I don't know how.

Comment: unrelated to vertical space but use `\exp`  (never use math italic for multi-letter identifiers it is designed to separate the letters so it looks like e times x times p (for same reason use `\mathrm{sc}` and `\mathrm{oc}`)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Common advice is to insert a `\mathstrut`, which is an invisible construct of zero width and vertical dimensions like a parenthesis. But that is not tall enough to do the trick here. You could insert a strut of your own making, i.e., a zero width rule of suitable height, into the denominator, but that is a bit error prone. So you could pick up a trick from an [old answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/how-to-raise-a-subscript/5192#5192):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisemath}[1]{\mathpalette{\raisem@th{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raisem@th}[3]{\raisebox{#1}{$#2#3$}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\frac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta
      T}{\raisemath{-1pt}{nN_sV_t}}\right)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(Incidentally, use `\exp` for the exponential function.)

Comment: Or, instead of writing `\mathstrut`, write `^{\mathstrut}`.

Comment: @Mico Clever. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

When you nest fractions like that, they get "squeezed". Maybe `\dfrac` is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[ I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\dfrac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: \dfrac in \exp - result]

Answer (score 3):

You can use  the `\mfrac` (medium-sized fraction) from `nccmath`, which looks better anyway in nested fraction, with or without a `\mathstrut`, or `\cfrac` with the pair `\biggl(...\biggr)` in the place of `\left(...\right)`. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

 \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\frac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\mfrac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\mfrac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)^{\mathstrut}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\biggl(\cfrac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\biggr)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{\exp\left(\cfrac{V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T}{nN_sV_t}\right)}
\end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You got a little runaway code in there. (Code as text) :)

Comment: Oh! yes. I didn't check where the cursor was when I inserted the image. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would consist of not using `\frac` in the denominator and, instead, using inline-fraction notation. A benefit of taking this approach is that the symbols and letters won't be so tiny.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{I_{sc_n}+K_i\Delta T}{%
\exp[(V_{oc_n}+K_v\Delta T)/(nN_sV_t)]}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```