# A math-font-size-knowledgeable \raisebox

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, math-fonts

I would like to some symbols lower than others in a math formula, without size change, for example

```
\def\abcd#1#2{\left[\raisebox{-.4em}{{\ensuremath{#1}}}\kern-.3em\setminus\kern-.2em#2\right]}
$\abcd{X_1}{X_2}$
```

which gives [image]

But when I use this notation in a subscript position `$$\bigoplus_{\abcd{X_1}{X_2}}$$`, the left glyph remains at normalsize (because of the `\raisebox` acting like a `\hbox` and ignoring the fact that it is located in a subscript):

[image]

How can I define a math-font-size-knowledgeable `\raisebox` command?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\mathpalette` plain TeX macro:

```
\def\abcd#1#2{\left[\mathpalette\abcdA{#1}\mkern-6mu{\setminus}#2\right]}
\def\abcdA#1#2{\lower.4em\hbox{$#1#2$}}
```

Moreover, the `\setminus` is re-typed as Ord using `{\setminus}`, so you needn't compensate the space after it by negative kern. And the first negative kern is expressed in `mu` units in order to work in script sizes too.

Comment: It works, thanks! Boy is the`\mathpalette` macro weird!

Comment: `\backslash` has been in plain TeX from day 1.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to guess the amount of lowering. It's necessary to use `\mathpalette` in order to use the right font size. See [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\abcd}[2]{\left[\mathpalette\abcd@{#1}\backslash#2\right]}
\newcommand{\abcd@}[2]{%
  % #1 = math style
  % #2 = text to be lowered
  \raisebox{%
    % we make it so that the top of the
    % lowered part is at the formula axis
    \dimexpr-\height+\abcd@fontdimen{#1}%
  }{%
    % we don't want that \scriptspace kicks in
    \scriptspace=\z@
    % the part to be lowered
    $\m@th#1#2$%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\abcd@fontdimen}[1]{%
  % the height of the formula axis is \fontdimen22 <math font of family 2>
  \fontdimen22
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 2
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\abcd{X_1}{X_2}\qquad\bigoplus_{\abcd{X_1}{X_2}}
\]
\[
\abcd{X}{Y}\qquad\bigoplus_{\abcd{X}{Y}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]