# is it possible to change the depth of subscripts?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have the following formula:

```
$ F_{\!\bm{H}}  F_{\overline{\!\!\bm{H}\!}} $
```

In this case both subscripts end at different depths (but start at the same height). I'd like them to end at the same depth. Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
F_{\!\bm{H}\vphantom{\overline{\!\!\bm{H}\!}}} F_{\overline{\!\!\bm{H}\!}}
```

The `\vphantom` command makes vertical space the same height its argument.  Depending on how often you need this or how predictable it is, you might be able to make a macro to add the `\vphantom` part automatically.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look at the [subdepth](http://ctan.org/pkg/subdepth) package, which has descrption

> This package is based on code (posted
>   long ago to comp.text.tex by Donald
>   Arseneau) to equalise the height of
>   subscripts in maths. The default
>   behaviour is to place subscripts
>   slightly lower when there is a
>   superscript as well, but this can look
>   odd in some situations.

Comment: See also [Subscripts for primed variables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3223/1235) for an example of the default behaviour. (The accepted answer by Will Robertson advises to use his `subdepth` package ...)

Comment: The best thing since sliced bread!!! I can finally remove all the ugly \vphantom's from my documents! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ F_{\!\bm{H}}  F_{\,\smash[t]{\overline{\!\!\bm{H}\!}}} $
```

Answer (score 2):

The following changes the subscripts globally:

```
% for Plain with default CM-font
\fontdimen16\tensy=2.7pt
\fontdimen17\tensy=2.7pt
% Or more generally
\fontdimen16\textfont0=2.7pt
\fontdimen17\textfont0=2.7pt
$\rm Fe_2^{+2}Cr_2^{+2}O_4^{+2}$
\bye
```

Comment: One should note that this changes the subscript positions _globally_ even if you put in inside a group.