# Size of indices (sub- and super- scripts)

Tags: macros, fontsize, typography, subscripts, superscripts

I've been looking around for a way to change the size of indices (all through the manuscript).

I found a lot of stuff, which could work, but I refuse to use *without understandind*. (See for example [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/redefine-the-default-depth-of-superscript-and-subscript-document-wide))

I while ago, I asked about changing the size of the `\wedge` symbol and the answer was to define a command

```
\newcommand{\w}{{\scriptstyle\wedge}}
```

**Question**

Is is possible to define something to make all indices a bit smaller?

Comment: It would help if you would post a link to some of the 'stuff' you are wondering about.

Comment: @carsten Sure, I edited the post to include a link. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathSizes`; here's what LaTeX has by default:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

What does this mean? Let's look at the line

```
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
```

When the current size is 10pt (`\@xpt` is a synonym), LaTeX uses 10pt size for normal math, 7pt size for first level sub/superscripts, 5pt for the second level.

If you want to get smaller subscripts, you could say

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{6}{4.5}
\makeatother
```

### Example

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{6}{4.5}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a_{b_c}$
\end{document}
```

Usage of `fix-cm` is necessary to get font size less than 5pt; alternatively you can load `lmodern`.

Here is the output; top the “reduced size”, bottom the normal output.

[image]

[image]

You'll need to redeclare math sizes for all font sizes you need.