# What are the fontdimen s13,s14,s15,s16,s17 exactly?

Tags: fonts, superscripts

“[What do different `\fontdimen<num>` mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88993/54601)” lists but does not mention how these three font dimensions are used. I could not find this information anywhere. All I could figure out was that changing s14 affects the usual superscript position, but could not find out how s13 and s15 were used. Even “[Redefine the default depth of superscript and subscript document-wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46622/54601)” does not bother to change s15. So what are they really?

Edit: I've provided my own rough answer after seeing *cfr*'s examples and fiddling with many more.

Comment: See *The TeXbook*, Appendix G, page 447, **Summary of parameter usage.** Also, rule 18c on page 445.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: And where can I find **that**? Is it available online? If not, do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: No, the source code is available in CTAN  but compilation is forbidden. You can buy it. I provided the reference, but I'd rather let a TeX font expert to answer this.

Comment: They are all to do with the positioning of superscripts. if we are talking about sigma 13-15 (sup 1-3). Which one is used depends on the current style used for typesetting. (I think one is used in display, one is used for scriptscript, one is used for other cases. But it is a while since I read this last.)

Comment: @Werner Do you think that is right?

Comment: @cfr: I don't know who has privileges to display the content. A quick search on [Google for `texbook type:pdf`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=texbook%20filetype%3Apdf) yields at least two...

Comment: @Werner But it is not meant to be, legally, is it? There is no permission to compile it, never mind distribute it. At least, for the finalised version. I don't know about the pre-indexed version you linked to.

Comment: @cfr: Neither do I... :-/

Comment: @cfr: I doubt it has to do with whether it is text or script or script-script, because that is what `\fontdimen13\scriptfont2` and `\fontdimen13\scriptscriptfont2` is for. But thanks a lot for providing examples where they actually cause an effect! I'll investigate further based on those.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I see, thanks. But I don't want to buy a book just to find out this one thing...

Comment: @user21820 There are a whole bunch of different styles: `D, D', T, T', S, S',...` and which of 13, 14, 15 is used *and* which of `\textfont2`, `\scriptfont2` and `\scriptscriptfont2` is used to establish 13, 14 and 15 depends on the current style and the current style's place in the hierarchy of styles. (It depends on `C'`, I think, as well as `C` where `C` is the current style.)

Comment: For something like this, where you only want to read a little bit, you can just read the TeX Book source. Obviously, that would be tedious if you wanted to read the whole thing, but then it would be worth buying the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so here's my own answer, which I think is good enough for all those people like me who just want a rough guide as to what the numbers mean.

**`\textfont2`** = normal math font

**`\scriptfont2`** = script math font

**`\scriptscriptfont2`** = script-script math font

**`\fontdimen13`** = display-style superscript height

**`\fontdimen14`** = text-style non-fraction superscript height

**`\fontdimen15`** = text-style fraction numerator/denominator superscript height

**`\fontdimen16`** = subscript normal depth

**`\fontdimen17`** = subscript changed depth if superscript is too close

**script math** = superscript/subscript/tfrac/overset/... at first level (text-style by default)

**script-script math** = script math from second level onwards

**display-style** = displayed equations or when `\displaystyle` is used in the current group

**text-style** = inline equations or when `\textstyle` is used in the current group

Don't ask me why s13,s14,s15 are so different from s16,s17. I expected corresponding parameters for superscripts and subscripts, but obviously the designer didn't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an illustration would help...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newdimen\savedimen
\begin{document}
Control
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\hrule
\verb|\fontdimen13| $\sigma_{13}$
\savedimen=\fontdimen13\textfont2
\fontdimen13\textfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen13\textfont2=\savedimen
\savedimen=\fontdimen13\scriptfont2
\fontdimen13\scriptfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen13\scriptfont2=\savedimen
\hrule
\verb|\fontdimen14| $\sigma_{14}$
\savedimen=\fontdimen14\scriptfont2
\fontdimen14\scriptfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen14\scriptfont2=\savedimen
\savedimen=\fontdimen14\scriptscriptfont2
\fontdimen14\scriptscriptfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen14\scriptscriptfont2=\savedimen
\hrule
\verb|\fontdimen15| $\sigma_{15}$
\savedimen=\fontdimen15\textfont2
\fontdimen15\textfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen15\textfont2=\savedimen
\savedimen=\fontdimen15\scriptfont2
\fontdimen15\scriptfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\fontdimen15\scriptfont2=\savedimen
\savedimen=\fontdimen15\scriptscriptfont2
\fontdimen15\scriptscriptfont2=25pt
\[
  x^{x^{x^{x^x}}} \frac{1}{x^{x^{x^x}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: examples]