# How to use properly the indices in Latex editor like `Tex studio`?

Tags: indexing, subscripts

How to use properly the indices in Latex editor like `Tex studio` ?

For example, when I am typing $x^{p_{q_r}}$, it looks like $p$ and $q$ sits side by side and $r$ is at down. But these are all proper subscript. What should I use for more clear position ?

In case of two indices (one is subscript of other), everything looks fine, but in case three indices it looks not good. What is salvation ?

For example, see

[image]

Comment: For manual tweaking there is always `raisebox`.

Comment: @oliversm, I didn't get you.Can please explain it?

Comment: (a) Can you include a full MWE showing this? In my standard set-up the output of $x^{p_{q_r}}$ looks just fine. (b) oliversm means that if the output has the symbols too high or too low in your opinion, you can always vertically shift it manually using the `\raisebox` command. http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_148.html But I doubt you would want to do it manually everytime you run into this.

Comment: @WillieWong, Please see the image in the question above. I used $x_1^{q_{1_1}}$ but it looks $q$ and $1$ sits together. i want to put them in proper subscript position .  How would be the code using `\raisebox` ?  What is the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I suggest to define a macro to save some typing and to avoid inconsistent layout. Modify the length `-0.2ex` to shift the index of *q*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\xq[2]{x_{#2}^{q\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$_{{}_{{#1}_{#2}}}$}}}
\begin{document}
$\xq11 \xq12 \cdots \xq1d$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is `\newcommand\xq[2]{x_{#2}^{q\raisebox{-0.2ex}{$_{{}_{{#1}_{#2}}}$}}}`  a command ?

Comment: Yes,it worked, but why $ \xqd1 \xqd2 \cdots \xqdd $  is giving error replacing 1 by  d ?

Comment: Because `\xqd` is taken to be the name of the macro, which does not exist. Either add a space, `\xq d1`, or use braces: `\xq{d}{1}`

Comment: `\newcommand` defines a macro/a shortcut. In this case the name of the shortcut is `\xq`, and it takes two arguments (therefore `[2]`), which are references by `#1` and `#2` in the text of the shortcut.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the issue is primarily that the shape of the lower case q, with a descender, makes it looks almost level with the 2nd level subscript 1. If you look at the base of the second level subscript 1, it is clearly lower than the bottom of the "loop" in q.

So what you need to do is to modify how much the subscripts are lowered. You can control this by setting `\fontdim` for the appropriate lengths. A discussion of how this works can be found [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256529/what-are-the-fontdimen-s13-s14-s15-s16-s17-exactly).

To illustrate the method, see the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter    %%% These three lines are to ensure the math fonts 
\check@mathfonts %%% are configured prior the call of \fontdim. Include
\makeatother     %%% if you run into an error about \nullfont.

\begin{document}
\[ x^{q_{1_1}} \]   %% Standard format. For reference.

\fontdimen16\scriptfont2=3pt  % <--- This is the line that sets the height.

\[ x^{q_{1_1}} \]  %% Same expression, for comparison. 
\end{document}
```

The output (top line is original, bottom line is with the increased subscript height):

[image]

You will have to play around with the parameters to find what makes you pleased aesthetically.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Why \\[ x^{q_{k_j}} \\]  showing error ?  Why not replacement of the indices allowed ?

Comment: What error? If you just replace `1_1` by `k_j` in the sample code I posted, it should compile with no problem. Please be more precise about the error you see.

Comment: Actually when I am using \[ x^{q_{k_j}} \]   within a math-expression like $f(x)=g(\[ x^{q_{k_j}} \])$, it showing but when I am writing it simply \[ x^{q_{k_j}} \] without any $ $ quotation, it is working fine. Anyway using your package mentioned above and using the fontdim above, I am just using  x^{q_{k_j}} and it looks `now` nice