# How to control the horizontal location of subscript?

Tags: spacing, subscripts

Sometimes I find the subscript is located too far from the letter (to which it is the subscript) such as in

```
\mathbf{v_{_\text{B}}}
```

How to get the subcript closer to the letter?

Comment: Try `\mathbf{v_{\mkern-4mu_\text{B}}}`. However, are you interested in a general solution?

Comment: May be related [is it possible to change the depth of subscripts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10286/15717)

Comment: (1) `B` in your example doesn't seem to be "text", but rather "math symbol to be typeset non-slanted", therefore you might want to use `\mathup{B}` or `\mathrm{B}` in place of `\text{B}`. (2) Is there any specific reason why you want to do double subscript `\mathbf{v}_{_\mathrm{B}}` instead of simple `\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{B}}` ?

Comment: That's a very odd markup, when would you ever want `_{_` that is a subscript consisting of an empty base with a subsubscript?

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the size of the subscript is not the right solution, in my opinion. And `\text` is not the correct command to use, because it doesn't ensure an upright font, for instance in the statement of a theorem printed in italics.

A "double subscript" is definitely not the best way to reduce the size, in any case.

If you really need to push a bit down the subscript, add an empty superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{v}^{}_\textnormal{B}$ is good

$\mathbf{v}_{\scriptscriptstyle\textnormal{B}}$ is not so good

$\mathbf{v_{_\text{B}}}$ is bad
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another way to get smaller caps is `\( x_\textnormal{\scshape b} \)`.

Comment: To be honest, I understand the OP's desire to make the `B` smaller. In the "good" version, the subscript `B` looks as big as the `v`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt I don't; if it's an uppercase B, so be it.