# Subscript vertical position dependent on presence of superscript - how to change?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subscripts, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscripts for primed variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/subscripts-for-primed-variables)

If I have a variable which is always subscripted but only sometimes superscripted, the vertical position of the subscript varies. For instance, `$s^*_i$`  and `$s^{}_i$` are different from `$s_i$`. Can I define the subscript such that it is always in the same position regardless of the presence of a superscript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\usepackage{subdepth}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\begin{document}
$a_i a_i^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I would define a macro to handle this in a consistent way. The following minimal example defines `\var[<var>]{<sub>}[<sup>]` that sets `<var>_{<sub>}^{<sup>}` (`<var>` and `<sup>` are optional). The addition of an empty `<sup>` ensures a consistent height for your superscripts. If your optional `<sup>` is something other than a "normal superscript" (let's call it "bizarre"), adding `\vphantom{<bizarre sup>}` before `#3` should take care of the vertical alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\var}{O{s} m O{}}{%
  \ensuremath{#1_{#2}^{#3}}% add \vphantom{<bizarre sup>}
}
\begin{document}
$s_i\ s_i^*$\ \var{i}\ \var{i}[*]\ \var[a]{k}\ \var[a]{k}[*]
\end{document}​
```

`<var>` has a default of `s`. If `<sup>` contains other (more complex) elements, you could use `\mathstrut`. That is, with some knowledge of the input, you can optimise the output.

It would also be possible to modify the macro to allow you to use superscript notation `^{..}` as needed, rather than an optional `<sup>` argument, but this enforce the use of math mode, rather than using `\ensuremath`.

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides the macro definition interface.

Comment: Actually `^{}` is sufficient (no need of `\vphantom`). And here `\ensuremath` is very questionable.

Comment: @egreg: I've incorporated your first suggestion. :)

Comment: Thanks -- elegant but I will keep this in mind as an example of xparse...