# Uniform vertical subscript alignment

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I was a bit annoyed that the vertical position of subscripts depends on whether or not a superscript is present:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$A_{xx}^{-1}A_{xx}$ vs $A_{xx}^{-1}A_{xy}^{}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This has been discussed before: [Subscript vertical position dependent on presence of superscript - how to change?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51678/119955) and [Subscripts for primed variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3223/119955).
There appear to be 2 solutions: either add `^{}` everywhere, or use the `subdepth` package. However the former clutters code and I was wondering whether one could just tell tex to automatically include "empty" subscripts/superscripts if not provided. I discovered however that this has a strange effect: it spaces out variables horizontally.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ \\
$a^{}_{}b^{}_{}c^{}_{}d^{}_{}e^{}_{}f^{}_{}g^{}_{}h^{}_{}i^{}_{}j^{}_{}k^{}_{}l^{}_{}m^{}_{}n^{}_{}o^{}_{}p^{}_{}q^{}_{}r^{}_{}s^{}_{}t^{}_{}u^{}_{}v^{}_{}w^{}_{}x^{}_{}y^{}_{}z^{}_{}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does TeX add these horizontal spaces, even when all these sub/superscripts are empty? And what is the recommended way in 2019 to achieve uniform subscript alignment? (To be honest it feels really weird that adding "nothing" changes the formatting of the text!)

Comment: TeX increases the width of the box holding a sub/superscript by `\scriptspace`, regardless of whether the box is empty or not.