# Difference in height of subscript

Tags: subscripts

I have a problem concerning the following equation in LaTeX:

```
A_{1}^{\ast} A_{1} = A_{1} A_{1}^{\ast}
```

where the 1's under the A's are placed at different heights. Does anyone know a simple way to fix this?

Comment: See, e.g., [Subscripts for primed variables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3223) (possible duplicate?)

Comment: I couldn't find this page and it does provide an easy way to fix it (using the package subdepth), so this is an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the lack of a superscript that's creating the problem.  Because of the size of the superscript, the subscript was pushed down.  Use a phantom superscript to equalize things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[
    A_{1}^{\ast} A_{1}^{\phantom{\ast}} = A_{1}^{\phantom{\ast}} A_{1}^{\ast}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed an easy way to fix it, but the answer given in the above duplicate gives an easier way by simply adding the 'subdepth' package.

Comment: `\vphantom` would be better than just `\phantom` -- look at the spacing between the subscript on the first *A* and the start of the second *A* in each pair to see why.  not a big difference here, but it could be in other situations.