# How to align horizontally symbols in superscript

Tags: vertical-alignment, superscripts, resize

I would like to align horizontally the two resized circles in the superscript in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
$A^{  \mathlarger{\circ}\mathsmaller{\circ} } $  
\end{document}
```

A related question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201178/how-to-create-horizontally-aligned-subscripts-in-latex), but it does not seem to give the solution for this specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A^{\substack{ \mathlarger{\circ}\\[-0.75ex]\mathsmaller{\circ}}} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

For an alignment of the symbols on the same axis, you can use this code:

```
$A^{\raisebox{\height}{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{$ \mathlarger{\circ} $}\raisebox{-0.5\height}{$ \mathsmaller{\circ} $}}} $
```

[image]

*Edit*: On the suggestion of @Campa, the `\vcenter` TeX primitive results is a simpler code  for the horizontal alignment:

```
$ A^{\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathlarger{\circ}$}}\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathsmaller{\circ}$}}} $
```

Comment: No, sorry, I meant that I would like to align them horizontally. I revised my question for clarity.

Comment: @James: I've added something that corresponds to what you want, if I understand it well.

Comment: The TeX primitive `\vcenter` comes in handy to centre something on the math axis.

Comment: @campa: Thanks for the suggestion! I've completed my answer (with due credits, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I'd define a special `\xcirc` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xcirc}[1][]{%
  % ensure it's used in math and consider it as an Ord atom
  % \mathpalette will remember the current math style
  \mathord{\mathpalette{\james@xcirc}{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\james@xcirc}[2]{%
  % center vertically with respect to the math axis
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1\@nameuse{james@#2@size}{\circ}$}}%
}
\let\james@@size\@firstofone
\let\james@l@size\mathlarger
\let\james@s@size\mathsmaller
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A^{\xcirc[l]\xcirc[s]}$

$\scriptstyle A^{\xcirc[l]\xcirc[s]}$

{\Large $A^{\xcirc[l]\xcirc[s]}$\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to ease input, the optional argument to `\xcirc` is just a letter (`l` for “larger”, `s` for “smaller”) and I define `\james@<arg>@size` for translating it into the correct call of `\mathlarger` or `\mathsmaller` (no optional argument will use the standard size, like `{\circ}`).

You might want to allow `\xcirc[ll]` by adding

```
\newcommand{\james@ll@size}[1]{%
  \mathlarger{\mathlarger{#1}}%
}
```

so you apply `\mathlarger` twice. Similarly for `\xcirc[ss]`.

Comment: @Bernard, I could not get the ll size to work, see this minimal working example https://ufile.io/ilk24 . May you please help me with this? Thank you.